# Gitlab SSH shell in Docker behind an ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, gitlab

I'm wondering what is the best solution to following case:

I'm running Gitlab CE on EC2 instance with Docker (Gitlab shell port is 2222) and Gitlab is behind an ELB. How should I proxy trafic to Gitlab ssh shell ? Throught the ELB or in some other way ? I don't want this instance to be accessible for the outside world.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/#details